# How would I implement a SJF and Round Robin scheduling simulator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, struct, scheduling

I have a vector of structs, with the structs looking like this:

```
struct myData{
    int ID;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
};
```

After populating my vector with this data:

```
1 1 5
2 3 2
3 5 10
```

where each row is an individual struct's ID, arrivalTime, and burstTime, how would I use "for" or "while" loops to step through my vector's indices and calculate the data in a way that I could print something like this out:

```
Time 0 Processor is Idle
Time 1 Process 1 is running
Time 3 Process 2 is running
Time 5 Process 1 is running
Time 8 Process 3 is running
```

I know that SJF and RR scheduling are pretty similar with the exception that RR has the time quantum so that no process can last longer than a arbitrary time limit before being pre-empted by another process. With that in mind, I think that after I implement SJF, RR will come easily with just a few modifications of the SJF algorithm.

The way I thought about implementing SJF is to sort the vector based on arrival times first, then if two or more vector indices have the same arrival time, sort it based on shortest burstTime first. After that, using

```
int currentTime = 0;
```

to keep track of how much time has passed, and

```
int i = 0;
```

to use as the index of my vector and to control a "while" loop, how would I implement an algorithm that allows me to print out my desired output shown above? I have a general idea of what needs to happen, but I can't seem to lay it all out in code in a way that works.

I know that whenever the currentTime is less than the next soonest arrivalTime, then that means the processor is idle and currentTime needs to be set to this arrivalTime.

If the vector[i+1].arrivalTime < currentTime + vector[i].burstTime, I need to set the vector[i].burstTime to vector[i+1].arrivalTime - currentTime, then set currentTime to vector[i+1].arrivalTime, then print out currentTime and the process ID

I know that these are simple mathematical operations to implement but I cant think of how to lay it all out in a way that works the way I want it to. The way it loops around and how sometimes a few processes have the same arrival times throws me off. Do I need more variables to keep track of what is going on? Should I shift the arrival times of all the items in the vector every time a process is pre-empted and interrupted by a newer process with a shorter burst time? Any help in C++ code or even psuedo-code would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I am pretty solid on the concept of how SJF works but I'm just having trouble translating what I understand into code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I know that SJF and RR scheduling are pretty similar with the exception that RR has the time quantum so that no process can last longer than a arbitrary time limit before being pre-empted by another process.

I don't think that's right. At least that's not how I learned it. RR is closer to FCFS (first come, first served) than it is to SJF.

One way to implement SJF is to insert incoming jobs into the pending list based on the running time. The insert position is at the end if this the new job's running time is longer than that of the job at the end; otherwise it's before the first job with a running time longer than the incoming job. Scheduling is easy: Remove the job at the head of the pending list and run that job to completion. A job with a long running time might not ever be run if short jobs keep coming in and getting processed ahead of that job with a long running time.

One way to implement round robin is to use a FIFO, just like with FCFS. New jobs are added to the end of the queue. Scheduling is once again easy: Remove the job at the head of the queue and process it. So far, this is exactly what FCFS does. The two differ in that RR has a limit on how long a job can be run. If the job takes longer than some time quantum to finish, the job is run for only that amount of time and then it is added back to the end of the queue. Note that with this formulation, RR is equivalent to FCFS if the time quantum is longer than the running time of the longest running job.

I suppose you could insert those incomplete jobs back into in the middle of the process list as SJF does, but that doesn't seem very round-robinish to me, and the scheduling would be a good deal hairier. You couldn't use the "always run the job at the head" scheduling rule because then all you would have is SJF, just made more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I see what you mean by saying RR is closer to FCFS. I think I forgot to mention that I need to implement a pre-emptive SJF algorithm, and I'm not sure whether that would change what you've told me so far.

Comment: That's just a refinement on SJF. When a new job comes in, compare it's burstTime to the time remaining on the current job. For a greater value, just insert that new job in the queue per SJF. Otherwise you stop the current job, insert the current job at the head of the queue (it has to have the shortest running time), and start processing the new job that just came in.